# Get the DDL of all the tables in teradata as a resultset

Tags: sql, teradata

Is there a way that I can extract the DDL of all the tables in one single query.

```
select DatabaseName,TableName,RequestText from db.tables;
```

gives the database name , table name and the last DDL on the table. But is it possible to get DDL to create the tables in form of resultset to a query instead of querying show db.tableName several times

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sel 'show table ' || databasename   ||'.'||   tablename ||';'  
from dbc.tables where databasename = 'dbname' and tablekind = 'T';
```

and then you can execute the output of this query to get the DDL like:

```
show table dbname.sometablename;
```

Comment: But it is like running many queries. I wanted to get it in single query like in the order of 1.

Comment: @DeepakRam:- I dont think there is any such way to get it in one single query!

Comment: If you put this into a BTEQ script you can EXPORT the output of the SELECT query and then turn around and run the output in the same BTEQ script.